# htaccess redirection for double slashes

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am having a problem with my site. Sometimes after the user log in is redirected to a page like this:

```
mydomain.com//somepage
```

Please notice the double slash in the URL, which takes to a not valid page so i want to modify my htaccess in order to make all pages with double slash to automatically redirect to an URL like this:

```
mydomain.com/folder/somepage
```

Please notice the word "folder" between slashes this time. An URL like this would always take to a valid page.

I made some rewrite rules for my htaccess but they dont work as expected:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ //([^\?\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /folder/%1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Could you please give me a hint?

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you getting the malformed URI to begin with? I would worry about fixing that root cause rather than some band aid fix.

Comment: I have tried but i cant so i gave it up.

Comment: change RewriteCond with  `/([^\?\ ]*)`

Comment: Where should i put that?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ //([^\?\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /folder/%1 [L,R=301]
```

You need to match against the `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable because the URI gets normalized before it gets matched against the pattern of rewrite rules.

Comment: Thanks fro the code. Although it is not working for me. Maybe because im combining other rules. Please see again my question, i just added the new code.

Comment: @CainNuke you need to have all of your redirects **before** any routing rules. So that redirect needs to be right below `Rewritebase`

Comment: You mean `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ //([^\?\ ]*)` should be before `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]` ?

Comment: @CainNuke everything in my answer needs to be before everything that you have

Comment: Even before '<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>'?